# Ubuntu installer crashed but Ubuntu works

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, crash

Nearly the end of the installation, there was an message error, unfortunately I didn't take note of it (but it just said something like it would send a report to developers). When I restarted the PC I was surpriced because Ubuntu started without problems.

Is there any way to check if Ubuntu is correctly installed? Do you think I should re-install Ubuntu?

Comment: If all works well, there is no need to worry.

Comment: Personally I'd want to assess the installer messages (you forgot) before I trusted it to know it was all good, either via the sent report sitting on launchpad, or your logs in /var/log/installer/  (the messages are likely in `syslog`), but @Pilot6 is correct, most warnings can be ignored; but we can't provide advice without the actual error message.

Comment: `sudo apt install debsums ; sudo debsums -s`